# Do I have to avoid using objects if I want to unit-test them?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, object, dependency-injection

Say, I'm using some json libraries which provides an object `Json`:

```
object Json {
    def unapply[T](jsonStr:String)(implicit converter:Converter[T]) { ... }
}
```

I can use it in my scala code like this:

```
class MyLoginController {
    def login(request:Request) = {
        val loginInfo = Json.unapply[LoginInfo](request.body)
        // check(loginInfo.email)
        // check(loginInfo.password)
    }
}
```

It's works perfectly, but soon I found my self can't test it easily with mock. I can't find a way to mock the `Json.unapply`.

So I have to change my code to provide a trait and use dependency injection:

```
trait JsonParsable[T] {
   def parse(jsonStr:String)(implicit converter:Converter[T])
}

object JsonParser extends JsonParsable[T] {
   def parse(jsonStr:String)(implicit converter:Converter[T]) = Json.unapply(jsonStr)
}

class MyLoginController(jsonParser:JsonParsable[T]) {
    def login(request:Request) = {
        val loginInfo = jsonParser.parse[LoginInfo](request.body)
        // check(loginInfo.email)
        // check(loginInfo.password)
    }
}
```

And when I write unit test, I will mock a `JsonParsable` for the `MyLoginController`:

```
val fakeParser = mock[JsonParsable]
// ...
val controller = new MyLoginController(fakeParser)
// ...
```

My question is, do I have to do this to avoid using objects, just in order to make it testable?

I found previous code is simple and easy, but the later one is more complex :(